# Prevent database mining when users have full access

Tags: javascript, database, security, architecture, bots

I am currently in a situation as follows -

1. I am currently hosting a private webapp, which involves the sending of AJAX calls to the database server and displaying the results. (REST Architecture)
2. Users can query the database by toggling various buttons, which correspond to a specific query that performs the above operation.
3. Users have access to the entire database (product feature). However, we only allow the retrieval of a small portion of the database in a single call.

However, I do not want the user to be a able to create a bot that is able to recreate the entire database in a short period of time. At the moment, a user could easily do so by duplicating the HTTP request (access to JS script/packet analyzer).

I have considered the following solutions -

1. Bot detection algorithms
2. Captcha
3. iframe
4. disabling the ability to read source code/JS files with a custom browser

I would like to find out if any of these solutions are feasible, or if there are any better alternatives/architecture available. I just want to prevent the scrapping of the database.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: You may be able to do this in the webserver configuration.

Comment: If your API allows the access, then there's not a huge amount you can do to stop it.  As @Barmar suggested, you could limit the rate at which you accept queries from any given client to one every n-seconds, or allow only n-queries within a rolling period, making it as inconvenient as possible.  You could issue time-limited API keys to the users upon login, requiring them to re-authenticate periodically.  The action you're protecting is legitimate within your application, so anything you do to prevent abuse is likely to require inconveniencing the end user in some way.

Comment: I agree with @Witchfinder. However a persistent attacker would forgo the UI and simply send requests. This could be done a number of ways but one way to look at would be python with requests. If an attacker picked up upon these throttles they could limit the requests. They could also automate the login etc. I don't see an easy way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to implement CORS properly.  That will help with people who might be, say, scripting on localhost using a web browser.  It won't stop a determined attacker though.  Throttling is about the best you can do.

Comment: Rate limiting is usually pretty effective. There was a site that was mining our site to generate statistics about our users, but when we throttled the page they stopped. The only tricky thing is finding the sweet spot that doesn't inconvenience legitimate users.